# Is there any particular formulation of $Con(T)$ that makes $Con(T)$ derivable from $T$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

In the proof of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem in my textbook, it is required that we choose the formula $Drv$ to be one that satisfies certain additional properties, rather than any formula that represents the set ${\tt Drv}$. Such properties are used in the proof of "$Con(T)$ is not derivable from $T$". This makes me wonder, if we choose a $Drv$ that does not satisfy these properties, could it be true that $Con(T)$ is derivable from $T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly have to place *some* additional assumption on the derivability predicate beyond its defining the actual derivability relation in the standard model of arithmetic in order to avoid very silly behaviors (of which side-stepping the second incompleteness theorem is one).

For example, consider what happens if we shift from the usual derivability relation $\mathrm{Drv}$ to the following alternative:  $$\mbox{$\mathrm{Silly}(x,y)$ = "$\forall z\neg \mathrm{Drv}(\underline{\#\perp}, z)$ and $\mathrm{Drv}(x,y)$."}$$ Intuitively, $\mathrm{Silly}(x,y)$ says "$y$ is a proof of $x$ **and $T$ is consistent** (in the usual $\mathrm{Drv}$-based sense)." Trivially we have $$T\vdash\neg\exists y \mathrm{Silly}(\underline{\#\perp},y),$$ so the second incompleteness theorem fails for $\mathrm{Silly}$. However, since $T$ is consistent the formulas $\mathrm{Silly}$ and $\mathrm{Drv}$ define the same relation in $\mathbb{N}$.

---

OK, there's a natural objection here. The relation $\mathrm{Silly}$ defined above *defines*, but doesn't *represent in the theory $T$*, the derivability relation. This is because - per Godel! - $T$ isn't powerful enough to prove that the crucial first clause of $\mathrm{Silly}$'s definition holds.

However, we can get around this. Simply look at $$\mbox{$\mathrm{VerySilly}(x,y)=$ "$\forall z\le y\neg \mathrm{Drv}(\underline{\#\perp},z)$ and $\mathrm{Drv}(x,y)$."}$$ This successfully *represents* the derivability relation (since we've bounded the universal quantifier), but we still get trivial $T$-provability of the corresponding consistency analogue.

Comment: Why is $Con(T)$ more legitimate than $VerySilly$ as the formulation of the consistency of $T$?